# Why can't my units get more than 30 XP?

Tags: civilization-5

My units get to 30 XP and then stop earning experience. Any idea why?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Experience gained from combat with barbarians is capped at 30 xp. You need to fight city-states or other players to go beyond level 3.

Comment: This is to prevent XP farming, since you could theoretically leave a barbarian encampment alive and just kill the barbarians which it produces. You could level your units forever like this if it gave more than 30 XP.

Comment: It's still easy to farm experience by moving your units in range of a city-state, fortifying, and gaining the 2xp from being shot at by the city each turn.

Comment: yes there's also a mod u can use for unlimited xp vs barbarians kind of a cheat